# отображение textarea input в Опера

Tags: html, css, html5, input, textarea

```
<form name="newtopic_frm" action="/send.php" method="POST">

<input id="ptit" required type="text" name="ptit" maxlength="128">
<br><br>
<textarea required name="pbody" rows="32" cols="64"></textarea>
<br>
tags: 
<input id="ptag" type="text" name="ptag" maxlength="50" value="notag">
<br><br>
read: 
<select id="pacc" name="pacc">
<option selected value="1">all users</option>
<option value="2">my friends</option>
<option value="3">nobody</option>
</select>

comments: 
<select id="comacc" name="comacc">
<option value="1">all users</option>
<option selected value="2">my friends</option>
<option value="3">nobody</option>
</select>

<input type="hidden" name="ssv" value="8">
<input type="submit" value="  send  ">
</form>
```

настройки css:

```
/*new.php*/

#ptit{
    width: 540px;
    height: 20px;
}

#pbody{
    width: 540px;
}

#pacc{
    width: 100px;
}

#comacc{
    width: 100px;
    color: #f00;
}

#ptag{
    width: 330px;
    height: 20px;

}
```

+еще некоторые:

```
    select{
    font-size: 12px;


}

textarea{
    font-size: 14px;
    padding: 5px;

}

input,textarea,#selfile,select{
    background: #bbb;
    color: #161;
    border: 1px solid #333;
}
    input:hover,textarea:hover,#pacc:hover,#id:hover,#comacc:hover{
/*border: 2px solid #333;*/
background: #ddd;
color: #222;
}
```

Но я считаю, что проблема не у меня, а у Оперы. ИЛИ ??? ПОЧЕМУ так не одинаково отображается?

опера
[image: Опера]

---

Ффокс и ГулглеХром идентично отображают:
[image: Ффокс]

Можно как-то сиправить? Чтобы было так как на нижнем скриншоте.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

задайте ширину textarea:

```css
#pta {
  width: 540px;
  height: 600px; /* З
}
```

```html
<textarea id="pta" required name="pbody"></textarea>
```

Comment: ааа, у меня же есть в css #pbody , но в текстареа не было ИД. от блин.

Comment: я в css менял значение, удалял его - а толку не было потому что протупил.